Dynamic module aliasing in __init__.py works at runtime but is not recognized by Pylance in VSCode
I’m trying to create a clean alias for a submodule in my Python package by dynamically importing it in __init__.py and exposing it as a different name. While this works perfectly at runtime, Pylance in VSCode does not recognize the alias, and I lose autocomplete and type checking.
Here’s a minimal example of my setup:
my_package/
├── my_package/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── sub_module/
│   │   ├── example.py
└── test_script.py

Code:
my_package/sub_module/example.py
def example_function():
    return "Hello from example_function!"

my_package/init.py
import importlib
import sys
from types import ModuleType

# Dynamically import sub_module.example
example_module = importlib.import_module("my_package.sub_module.example")

# Create an alias `my_package.alias`
alias_module = ModuleType("my_package.alias")
alias_module.example_function = example_module.example_function

# Add the alias to sys.modules for dynamic imports
sys.modules["my_package.alias"] = alias_module

test_script.py
from my_package.alias import example_function

print(example_function())

Expected Behaviour:
Running test_script.py works perfectly and prints:
Hello from example_function!
Problem:
Pylance in VSCode shows the following error:
Import "my_package.alias" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)
Additionally, Pylance does not provide autocomplete or type checking for the alias.
Question:
How can I configure my project so that Pylance recognizes my_package.alias and provides type checking/autocomplete? I’d like to avoid using stub files or polluting the package structure if possible.
EDIT:
just for additional clarity.
I've tried lots of combinations of things like this in the init too:
# Import the actual module or function
import my_package.sub_module.example as alias

# Declare it as part of the package API
__all__ = ["alias"]

In the test script, this sort of thing just means I can do
import my_package
print(my_package.alias.example_function())

But nothing I do allow me to do a 'from' import alias i.e.
from my_package.alias import whatever


Why not just do the simple way in __init__.py using alias = importlib.import_module("my_package.sub_module.example") and then have 'alias' be present in __all__ to make that a re-export? Dynamic module/classes are going to have a hard time to get working using static analysis tools.

I tried this but unfortunately it doesn't work. Using this approach causes the test_script to fail altogether, and still does not resolve the pylance autocomplete issue.
